# Extremely slow wifi in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking

Okay so I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 (previously on 17.04).

My internet seems very slow. Here's the output of `lsusb`.

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Ubuntu has detected my usb wifi adapter. However speeds are slow.

Normally I get 300+ kb download speeds in terminal (while running apt-update & apt-get install, ***earlier***).

But now it's around 120-140kb.

here's output of `iwconfig`:

```
wlx00177c6993b1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"D-Link"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 9C:D6:43:80:31:28   
          Bit Rate=90 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:54  Invalid misc:661   Missed beacon:0

ens2      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I really need my net back working...

OS is fresh install.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not your ISP's fault?

Comment: Good question from @Android Dev. A method to sort of prove whether or not this is true is to work at very early times in the morning and late times in the night. If you see your 300 transfer rate at these times, I would say that traffic may be at least some of the problem. An ISP can also slow down  on purpose due to large data downloading. Also, though, we all need to remember that there an awful lot of us accessing the net, and the more the merrier is not always true.

Comment: yes it is not my isp's fault.

Comment: help plz? i need to fix this.